# Classic ASP - Dynamic array not working

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Im trying to create an array from a string i have but its not working, i was wondering if someone could let me know where im going wrong.

There could be quite a few filenames in the string, which is dynamic

My string is as follows:

```
imagesArray = "1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg"
```

My code is as follows:

```
fileNameArray = split(imagesArray, ",")

Dim newImageArray
Redim newImageArray(uBound(fileNameArray) + 1)

For each i in fileNameArray
    newImageArray(i) = i
Next
```

I keep getting a 500 error when i run this.

Comment: Turn off friendly errors and make sure the server is sending detailed errors to the browser. Alternately you could dig the detailed error from the logs or log the error details yourself. Behind that generic 500 error is a more detailed message that will help point to where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not working is you're using a For Each loop, where i is the object. You're then using the object as the index on the array as well as the value.

If you use the following, the code will work -

```
For i = 0 to UBound(fileNameArray)
    newImageArray(i) = i
Next
```

I suspect what you're actually looking for is -

```
fileNameArray = split(imagesArray, ",")

Dim newImageArray
Redim newImageArray(uBound(fileNameArray))

For i = 0 to uBound(fileNameArray)
    newImageArray(i) = fileNameArray(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This works! You can do anything with the output... write lines or assign variables.

```
if Instr(strData, ",") > 0 then 
    strArray = Split(strData, ",")
        for each x in strArray
            response.write(x & "<br>")
        next            
End if
```